# Send shellcode to interactive C program in Windows

Tags: python, c, exploit

I'm trying to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability in a C program, I have control of EIP but I don't know how to send the payload to the program. Here's the source:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    char name[32];
    printf("Enter your name and press ENTER\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Hi, %s!\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I insert the payload (BUFF + EIP + NOPs + Shellcode) in the name variable?
In Linux its some like $(python -c 'print "BUFF + EIP + NOPs + Shellcode') how can I do this in windows? If possible with a python script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If pipe functionality is not available, you can use a temporary file to pipe the payload.

As

```
python -c 'print "BUFF + EIP + NOPs + Shellcode' > payload.txt
vulnbrable_binary.exe < payload.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, I can do it in cmd.exe however in Immunity passing < payload.txt as an argument doesn't work.

Comment: In that case you can start the process externally from cmd and then attach immunity to it.

Comment: Also while selecting files to run with immunity you can specify command line arguments. You can try giving < payload.txt there

Comment: But now I can't send the payload

Comment: You can't send the payload by using which method? Starting externally and attaching? Or by using command line argument?

Comment: If I use vulnbrable_binary.exe < payload.txt the program terminates before I can attach it in Immunity

Comment: For the issue of the program terminating before attaching, you can add a DebugBreak() into the source code (assuming you are on windows). This will act like a break point. Then you can start the program, it will halt. Then attach and continue using the debugger.

Comment: Or you can use this `while(!IsDebuggerPresent()){Sleep(1);}`. This will cause the program to keep on looping till a debugger attaches.

Comment: For this exercise I have the source code however I need to get a working solution for when the source is not available. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I think you will use the debugger only for this example right (to see what is going on and debug). In the working solution you don't need a debugger. You can directly run it from cmd and you can expect it to work.

Comment: If you still need to debug, just use a main stream debugger like the Visual Studio debugger. It allows you to set any command (with < ).